# How to convert a specific array of bytes to image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

The specific structure of array is: first number= count of bytes, second number= width, third number= height, after these are 3 numbers for RBG for all of pixels.

Can I use a class or a method in iPhone SDK to convert these bytes to UIImage? Or do I have to write a function, which draw a picture from the byte array?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [CGImageCreate()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreate) which should allow you to create an image from data in a structured format. You can then create a `UIImage` from the resulting `CGImage`.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting that array, from some webService or you are creating in the coding side?

You can create an object of NSData Class

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData allc] initWith..];
```

see different methods available for the class.

Use this data object to create your image.

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: I'm getting the array from a network socket. It is in a NSMutableData and I hae to draw the picture from this.

Comment: using the method UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
should not be a problem for you then. Have you tried it?

Comment: This is not going to work. UIImage:initWithData: is for image data encoded in PNG, JPEG or another supported image format. However, here we're dealing with a custom, uncompressed format.

Comment: this was not told when the question was posted.